# I want to edit the Font Color tab in the Editing Tool part of the sharepoint ribbon

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to sharepoint and I want to edit the Font Color tab in the Editing Tool part of the sharepoint ribbon and want to show only some custom color insted of the default theme color menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer..
We can create our own custum themes using Power Point 2010 and then can upload it to sharepoint 2010 themes.
More details can be found on the below link..

http://blog.johnsworkshop.net/creating-a-sharepoint-theme-using-a-powerpoint-template/